# Adding an Audio object to my react state array

Tags: html, reactjs, audio

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')

    axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
        console.log(res.data.data.playList);
        this.setState({
            categories: res.data.data.playList,
            audioList: res.data.data.playList.url
        })
    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


}
```

In my `componentWillMount()` I get bunch of mp3 urls from a database and stores into a state called `audioList` so it has a bunch of URLs of a sound file. However, what I actually want to store is an `Audio` object (HTML5 Audio).

Usually, to make it playable, I would have to make a new `Audio` object like

```
this.audio = new Audio([URL]);
```

then do

```
this.audio.play()
```

Since I want to make a list of music, I would like to but everything like

```
this.state.audioList = [ audioObject1, audioObject2, audioObject3, ... ]
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')

    let playLists = [];

    axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
        //console.log(res.data.data.playList);
        res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => playLists.push(new Audio(value.url)));
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { audioList: playLists}
        }, () => console.log("dddd" + this.state.audioList));

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

This gives me

[image]

**EDIT2**

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')


let playLists = [];

axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
    //console.log(res.data.data.playList);
    res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => playLists.push(new Audio(value.url)));
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { audioList: playLists, categories: res.data.data.playList}
    });
}).catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with array `push` like below for objects available inside array,

```
let playlists = [];
res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => playlists.push(new Audio(value.url)));
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { audioList: playlists}
}, () => console.log(this.state.audioList));
```

Comment: is this supposed to happen inside componentWillMount?

Comment: Yes that is piece of code inside `axios` response. Is there any problem using this code in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: Can you please see my EDIT to see what the problem is?

Comment: You are initialised/defined array  `playLists` but used that as `playList`  in rest of place.

Comment: Oh ok. I fixed that but I also have to store `res.data.data.playList` into my `categories` as my EDIT2. This time im getting the error as above, and `console.log("dddd" + this.state.audioList)` doesn't show me anything

Comment: Yes you can't call `state` variable right after setting the state. Try to add inside first `setState` itself like `this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { audioList: playLists, categories: res.data.data.playLists }
})`

Comment: Also if you need to console it use callback section in `setState`. Please see the updated answer for `setState` callback method.

Comment: I've been mixing up the name of playlists and playList. I will try again and let you know.

Comment: Yes your data property may be `res.data.data.playList`. But used as `playLists`. I have updated your edits hope your problem will gets solved!

Comment: Thanks ! It successfully adds the audio object. If I want to make the first element to play, do I just simply have to do `this.state.audioList[0].play()` ?

Comment: Yes you can play if you want to test that. For dynamic set new method called `playAudio` and pass key to that and play using `this.state.audioList[key].play()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160835/discussion-between-dawn17-and-elumalai-kaliyaperumal).

Comment: Hello again. Is there a way to add the playLists into a normal array this.testList instead of a state in the line `   this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { audioList: playLists, categories: res.data.data.playList}
    });` ?